# SQL Server - no maintenance plan task name in Logs

Tags: sql, sql-server, maintenance-plan

I have weird bug in SSMS logs - after creating and running an maintenance plan it seems there is no subtask/plan names in Logs as shown below.

Any advice what went wrong?
[image]

Comment: This is still happening to me on SQL Server 2014 even though all tasks have names as described in the answer below.

Anyone else have an answer to this?

No it's not! I just noticed that "rename" task affects the "name" but not the "task name" property which is different!

Comment: Further comment - since I was called away just as I was editing the above and so lost my 5-minute editing window...

These Tasks have *two* properties, "Name" and "Task Name". The one displayed in the box on the SSIS design screen is "Name", and this is what is affected when you right-click and "rename" it. However, what is needed for the History display, is the "Task Name" property, which you have to scroll down to see!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, the solution was to Edit properties of each task to add TaskName property individually.

[image]